# Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TitleClient' with unique index 'XAK1TitleClient'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ever since I cleaned the data on the SQL Database I've been getting this issue, whereas on the unclean database the issue does not happen. When I run my stored procedure (huge procedure) it returns:

```
General SQL error. Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.TitleClient' with unique index 'XAK1TitleClient'. Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id_title', table 'Database.dbo.TitleCom'; column does not allow null, insert fails.
```

Is it possible that I deleted data from a table that **causes** this? Or is that impossible?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "cleaned"?

Comment: It's possible your insert statement includes values from a table you "cleaned."  Combined with a LEFT OUTER JOIN you are getting NULL where you used to get a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `dbo.TitleClient` have an identity column? You might need to run

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.TitleClient')
```

I'm guessing that the first message

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object 'dbo.TitleClient' with unique
>   index 'XAK1TitleClient'

is because the seed value is out of synch with the existing table values and the second error message

> Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'id_title', table
>   'Database.dbo.TitleCom' column does
>   not allow null, insert fails.

Comes from a failed attempt at inserting the result of `scope_identity` from the first statement.

Comment: DBBC CHECKIDENT('TitleClient') returned this message: Checking identity information: current identity value '34566', current column value '34566'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Comment: @John - And what if you try your stored procedure? (If that **was** the issue then the failed insert(s) must have bumped it back to the right value) if you still get the problem we are going to need some more details about what `unique index 'XAK1TitleClient'` is and how it is getting its values.

Comment: To be honest I don't even know where to visualize that unique index in management studio. I'm a beginner in SQL..

Comment: @John - In Management Studio can you right click the table and script the `CREATE` stateement and add it into your question. Also exand indexes and script the definition of `XAK1TitleClient`

Answer (score 0):

How cleanly did you "clean" the data?

- If some tables still have data, that might be causing a problem.
- Especially if you have triggers resulting in further inserts.

For you to investigate further.

- Take the body of your stored proc, and run it bit-by-bit.
- Eventually, you'll get to the actual statement producing the error.
- Of course if you aren't inserting into `dbo.TitleClient` at this point, then it's certainly a trigger causing problems.
- Either way: Now you can easily check the data inserted earlier in your proc to figure out the root cause.